# How to speed up svm.predict?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, object-detection

I'm writing a sliding window to extract features and feed it into CvSVM's predict function.
However, what I've stumbled upon is that the svm.predict function is relatively slow.

Basically the window slides thru the image with fixed stride length, on number of image scales.

- The speed traversing the image plus extracting features for each
  window takes around 1000 ms (1 sec).
- Inclusion of weak classifiers trained by adaboost resulted in around
  1200 ms (1.2 secs)
- However when I pass the features (which has been marked as positive
  by the weak classifiers) to svm.predict function, the overall speed
  slowed down to around 16000 ms ( 16 secs )
- Trying to collect all 'positive' features first, before passing to
  svm.predict utilizing TBB's threads resulted in 19000 ms ( 19 secs ), probably due to the overhead needed to create the threads, etc.

My OpenCV build was compiled to include both TBB (threading) and OpenCL (GPU) functions.

Has anyone managed to speed up OpenCV's SVM.predict function ?

I've been stuck in this issue for quite sometime, since it's frustrating to run this detection algorithm thru my test data for statistics and threshold adjustment.

Thanks a lot for reading thru this !

Comment: The decision function for SVM takes O(nSV * f) time, where nSV is the number of support vectors and f is the number of features. Can you inspect the SVM model to see how many support vectors it has?

Comment: I checked it, there's 4417 support vectors and the feature size is 3780.

Comment: That's a pretty large SVM. If you train with stronger regularization, the number of SVs might decrease.

Comment: Just from the top of your head, is it faster to use RandomForest than SVM ? (Disregarding the loss of accuracy)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not actually familiar with OpenCV. I just happen to have hacked on SVMs a bit.

Comment: It's okay. The insight that SVM's speed depends on nSV is more than enough for me.

Comment: Hi larsmans, you're correct. By adjusting C parameter on the svm, it allows me to have fewer support vectors. Now I can run the whole detection under 4 seconds. The downside is that it's no longer soft-margin version, and reduce in accuracy, but I can live with that.

Comment: I think you mean max-margin; high C actually gives softer margins. Posted my comments as an answer.

Comment: I find that the OpenMP version of libsvm works much faster than OpenCV's implementation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Answer posted to formalize my comments, above:)

The prediction algorithm for an SVM takes O(*nSV* * *f*) time, where *nSV* is the number of support vectors and *f* is the number of features. The number of support vectors can be reduced by training with stronger regularization, i.e. by increasing the hyperparameter *C* (possibly at a cost in predictive accuracy).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what features you are extracting but from the size of your feature (3780) I would say you are extracting HOG. There is a very robust, optimized, and fast way of HOG "prediction" in `cv::HOGDescriptor` class. All you need to do is to

1. extract your HOGs for training
2. put them in the svmLight format
3. use svmLight linear kernel to train a model
4. calculate the 3780 + 1 dimensional vector necessary for prediction
5. feed the vector to `setSvmDetector()` method of `cv::HOGDescriptor` object
6. use `detect()` or `detectMultiScale()` methods for detection

The following document has very good information about how to achieve what you are trying to do: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/trainHOG although I must warn you that there is a small problem in the original program, but it teaches you how to approach this problem properly.

Comment: Ah, there's a reason why I'm not using HOGDescriptor, because I'm extending it to use it on depth images using other features (e.g. normal of surface, etc). I need to train my own HoG and collect statistics as a baseline comparison to my other methods.

Comment: Well then use the technique that `HOGDescriptor` is using to speed things up. `HOGDescriptor` pre-calculates HOGs of each `cell` and stores them in a cache map, then the sliding window uses the pre-calculated numbers to speed things up. The only thing is that the sliding window has to move a cell size to make this method effective. You can not have a sliding window that moves a single pixel.

Comment: Well, the issue is not precalculating the HoG descriptor, the slowdown is in svm.predict. All those calculation of features using integral histogram for the entire window and scale space is quite fast for my need (~1 sec). But svm.predict slows down the whole thing considerably.

Comment: Use linear kernel, calculate the weighted vector representing the hyperplane of your SVM model (the way the above document describes), forget about `SVM.predict()` and do your own prediction by doing a dot product of your weighted vector and any given candidate vector.

Answer (score 0):

As Fred Foo has already mentioned, you have to reduce the number of support vectors. From my experience, 5-10% of the training base is enough to have a good level of prediction.

The other means to make it work faster:

1. reduce the size of the feature. 3780 is way too much. I'm not sure what this size of feature can describe in your case but from my experience, for example, a description of an image like the automobile logo can effectively be packed into size 150-200:

   - PCA can be used to reduce the size of the feature as well as reduce its "noise". There are examples of how it can be used with SVM;
   - if not helping - try other principles of image description, for example, LBP and/or LBP histograms
2. LDA (alone or with SVM) can also be used.
3. Try linear SVM first. It is much faster and your feature size 3780 (3780 dimensions) is more than enough of "space" to have good separation in higher dimensions if your sets are linearly separatable in principle. If not good enough - try RBF kernel with some pretty standard setup like C = 1 and gamma = 0.1. And only after that - POLY - the slowest one.