# How can i improve openCV people detecting algorithm

Tags: android, c++, algorithm, opencv, object-detection

I am trying to write human detector, it works now, but sometimes it reacts on cats/boxes etc., also i got like 5 fps. So the question is, how can i improve my algorithm for better fps and detection accuracy.

I have tried to use this one:
http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/11/09/pedestrian-detection-opencv/

But i couldnt find any way i could use this on android.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {    
        List<MatOfPoint> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Mat frame = new Mat();
            Mat gray = new Mat();
            Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
            Mat originalFrame = inputFrame.rgba();


            Imgproc.medianBlur(originalFrame,originalFrame,3);
            Imgproc.cvtColor(originalFrame, gray, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);

            HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor();
            //Получаем стандартный определитель людей и устанавливаем его нашему дескриптору
            MatOfFloat descriptors = HOGDescriptor.getDefaultPeopleDetector();
            hog.setSVMDetector(descriptors);
            MatOfRect locations = new MatOfRect();
            MatOfDouble weights = new MatOfDouble();
            hog.detectMultiScale(gray, locations, weights);

            Point rectPoint1 = new Point();
            Point rectPoint2 = new Point();
            Point fontPoint = new Point();

            if (locations.rows() > 0) {
                List<Rect> rectangles = locations.toList();
                for (Rect rect : rectangles) {
                    rectPoint1.x = rect.x;
                    rectPoint1.y = rect.y;
                    fontPoint.x  = rect.x;
                    fontPoint.y  = rect.y - 4;
                    rectPoint2.x = rect.x + rect.width;
                    rectPoint2.y = rect.y + rect.height;
                    final Scalar rectColor = new Scalar( 0  , 0 , 0  );
                    // Добавляем на изображения найденную информацию
                    Imgproc.rectangle(originalFrame, rectPoint1, rectPoint2, rectColor, 2);
                }
            }


            frame.release();
            gray.release();
            hierarchy.release();
            list.clear();

            return originalFrame;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the HOG+SVM approach to detect people; it is inherently going to be quite slow. Never the less, you can use some of the suggestions in this question [How to speed up svm.predict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191858/how-to-speed-up-svm-predict)

Depending on your problem, i.e. if the camera is static and the pedestrians are moving you could opt for a background subtraction approach this is probably the most efficient way but bear in mind that this will pick up any objects that are moving in the scene, so you could include thresholds to remove small objects. Some background subtraction algorithms include mixture of gaussian (MOG) or MOG2 or GMG. Also, an important thing to note is that these approaches rely on creating a background model of the scene, i.e. they assume static pixels over time to be part of the background, hence, when a pedestrian stands still for a while in the scene they get embedded into the background resulting in miss detection. There are many papers out there that provide potential solutions to that problem so you might want to have a look at them, here is one that produces decent results: [Static and Moving Object Detection Using Flux Tensor with Split Gaussian Models](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_cvpr_workshops_2014/W12/papers/Wang_Static_and_Moving_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf)

Additionally, you could opt for a data driven approach, either get a good pre-trained model and do your detection using that or train one yourself using TensorFlow, Caffe or Torch and use the dnn opencv_contrib module to do the detection.